# Jar file name form java code

Tags: java, jar

I would like to determine the jar file name from my java code. I found many solutions in the google, but nothing works. Just to see what I tried here is a stackoverflow forum where a bunch of solutions is posted: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file)

I have Mac OS X 10.6.5.
When I type java -version I get this result:
`java version "1.6.0_22"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04-307-10M3261)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03-307, mixed mode)`

Thank you for your help.

---

Edit:
I edit my post to answer for the comment.
Some of the solutions gives me "null" value when I want to System.out.println the path and also fails when I want to create an instance of a File.
Other solutions when I ask for the path they don't give something like `file:/.....`, instead they give something like `rsch:/` or something like, this I don't know exactly, but it is a 4 character simple word.

---

Edit 2:
I run an executable jar from the console. And I would like to have this jar file name in the classes which are in the executed jar file.

---

Edit 3:
The 4 character word is: `rsrc:./`

Code how I got this:

```
    File file = null;
    try {
        System.out.println(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

Edit 4:
I also tried this code:

```
package core;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MyClass {

    public String getText(String key) {
        String path = "" + MyClass.class.getResource("../any.properties");
        File file = new File((path).substring(5, path.length()));

        Properties props = readProps(file);

        return props.getProperty(key);
    }

    private Properties readProps(File file) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream in = null;

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(file);
            props.load(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return props;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new MyClass().getText("anything"));
    }

    }
```

With this result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1937)
at core.PropHandler.getText(MyClass.java:14)
at core.PropHandler.main(MyClass.java:39)
... 5 more
```

This code perfectly runs in the eclipse, but when I create the runnable jar file I think you can see the problem.

Comment: The link you posted offers a few solutions. You say "nothing works" - can you elaborate on why they don't work?

Comment: Jar file name of *what*?

Comment: After the edits, I don't think the question deserves a -1.

Comment: Thank you for changing your mind!

Comment: I'm not the one who gave it -1 in the first place... just asking that person to reconsider. Your question is not particularly badly written or unclear.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Now I make another edit, because I found the 4 character word.

Comment: Looks like `MyClass` is a jar inside of another jar? or the other way around? The exception in your most recent addition, `InvocationTargetException` is caused by the substring() you use (just masked by some reflection used by eclipses jar-in-jar trickery)  - i recommend printing out the string before trying to use substring on it to avoid the exception and see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally this is the code which resolved my problem:

```
String sConfigFile = "any.properties";

InputStream in = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(sConfigFile);
if (in == null) {
    System.out.println("ugly error handling :D");
}
Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
try {
    props.load(in);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

With this way it founds my property file.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? http://www.uofr.net/~greg/java/get-resource-listing.html

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat test.java; javac test.java; jar cvf test.jar test.class; java -cp test.jar test
public class test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(test.class.getResource("test.class"));
 }
}
adding: META-INF/ (in=0) (out=0) (stored 0%)
adding: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (in=56) (out=56) (stored 0%)
adding: test.class (in=845) (out=515) (deflated 39%)
Total:
------
(in = 885) (out = 883) (deflated 0%)
jar:file:/tmp/test.jar!/test.class
```

For access to resources that works regardless of the presence of a jar file, I always use classname.class.getResourceAsStream(). But the linked document shows how to use JarFile() for the same purpose.

Comment: I did. You still used File(); had you used JarFile() instead, you could have accessed the properties with JarEntry.toString(). In any case, you got it working with getResourceAsStream(), which is simple and reliable.